# Advice on correlation

Tags: pearson-r

Dear Cross validated community,
I need some guidance with statistics on my sample set. I collected plants at 7 sites following an environmental gradient.

Data consists of
•   7 sites along spatial grid 
•   3 replicate samples for soil compound 1
•   3 replicate samples for soil compound 2
•   70 to 90 samples of plants per site, measuring both compound 1 and 2 in them.

I wanted to correlate the concentration of compound 1 (or 2) in the plants with the concentration of the same compound in the soil. But, understand these are not independent samples (so it violates Pearson).

Please advise. Ideally in SPSS terminology.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help with SPSS, but you don't want correlation, you want regression. You can then use a multilevel model or generalized estimating equations to deal with the dependent data.